# How to find trace methanol content in fermented fruit/distillate?

Tags: organic-chemistry, analytical-chemistry, alcohols

Suppose we have some fermented (optionally also distilled) fruit/fruit juice. The sample therefore contains water, sugars, ethanol etc. Which analysis method is the simplest to find out whether the toxic methanol is also present?

Answer (score 4):

Methanol, formed by degradation of pectines from the skin of fruits, as well as higher alcohols is volatile and does not show significant absorption in the UV.

Consequently, gas chromatography is the method of choice to determine these components in the fermentation mix.

Comment: Is this something that can be done on the run? Or at home a least?

Comment: @TomášZato No, [gas chromatography](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gas_chromatography) usually isn't something to be run at home. The prices for the equipment and the operation costs are too high.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try [NMR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nuclear_magnetic_resonance)?

But if the amount of the methanol is too small, you won't see so beautiful signal:

[image]

Comment: Nice answer! What program generates such a nice NMR-spectrum?

Comment: @andselisk I got this image from this site: https://www2.chemistry.msu.edu/faculty/reusch/virttxtjml/spectrpy/nmr/nmr2.htm to simulate NMR there are a lot of web-pages: https://web.chemdoodle.com/demos/simulate-nmr-and-ms/ it can predict OH (most of them can't) for example: www.nmrdb.org/new_predictor/ As software I prefer Mnova http://mestrelab.com/ or Chemdraw http://www.cambridgesoft.com/software/overview.aspx - both are not free.

Comment: I'm aware of both Mnova and Chemdraw, but to my knowledge  none of them can produce this pixel-perfect plot. But thank you anyway!

Comment: @andselisk Ususally, I prefer EXPERIMENTAL data bases, something like: http://sdbs.db.aist.go.jp/sdbs/cgi-bin/cre_index.cgi for small compound it is much better than prediction.  Here is small comparison http://imgur.com/a/EIjLW