# Is there an easy way to detect methanol in spirits (which may have been adulterated)?

Tags: alcohols

Is there an easy way to detect methanol in spirits, which, you suspect, may have been adulterated?

Comment: Related: [How to test for methanol?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/94551/how-to-test-for-methanol); [How to find trace methanol content in fermented fruit/distillate?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/10285/how-to-find-trace-methanol-content-in-fermented-fruit-distillate).

Comment: Thanks, I should've checked for similar questions first. I'm sorry.

Answer (score -1):

Well that depens on your possibilities.

a) Destillation / Boiling Point (easy, unsafe)

b) Refractive index (depends on impurities)

c) GC (best, very expensive)

d) 1H NMR